# When using Jupyter Notebook, can't read files on desktop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, python

No matter what Python approach I take to reading a file on the MacBook Pro desktop, I get a 'path does not exist' error message.  In Terminal, I find that a web of directories was created where Jupyter Notebook has a CWD on directory /home. Nothing in this network is visible on the Finder.  In Terminal, I did a cp file-on-desktop same-file-in-home-directory. I got error message that the /home directory path didn't exist. The computer is acting like the Jupyter Notebook created a disk partition. It can be seen in Terminal, but it isn't recognized by Finder or anything else in the Macos file management.  What do I do so that I can read/write twix a Jupyter Notebook and my MacBook Pro?

Comment: There is no `/home` directory on a Mac.  Can you rework your question with some additional details? As written it’s unclear what you’re referring to

Comment: WHat directory is the juypter kernel running from. Note all the commands are from where the kernel is.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the juypter installation.  I suggest you try your question in a juypter forum.  I found several juypter forums,   https://jupyter.org/community

Comment: As stated, /home is not visible to the Finder.  Inside the Notebook os.getcwd produces /home/dsxuser. When I use Terminal, I see /home when I do an ls after I cd .. back to the drive.  So, when the Notebook is running, I can see /home from the Notebook and from the Mac Terminal, but not in Finder.  historystamp is probably right.